# Syntactic mistake leads to downvotes. Keep or delete and re-ask?

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted a question where in the midst of simplifying my code for a more concise code sample in the question, I mistakenly had a line of code that had a method on the wrong object thereby confusing the reader. I left it and returned to find a few down votes. Realizing my error in the question I edited the post and fixed it but the down votes obviously remain. Due to this, it likely won't get any more attention or an answer to what I deem to valid and useful question for others. Should I delete the post and repost the fixed question starting with a clean slate or leave the question as is?

**Edit**: In regards to the marked duplicate question, this question does not reference the closure of a question and this specifically pinpoints changes where fixes to the syntax would inspire changes to the already acquired pre-change down votes.

Comment: Deleting it would hurt you more.  You wouldn't get a "clean slate" from the question since the deletion of a question would be attached to your account, and potentially count against you towards a question ban.

Comment: Let's stop pretending that question bans mean anything.  And of course it doesn't apply to the OP, he got plenty of love for his posts.  So yes, it makes perfect sense to delete and re-post.  A bounty does as well, you got plenty of rep.  But I guess you'll go for option #1 :)

Comment: Putting a bounty seems like a fantastic idea to me.